Gdalwarp() based orthorectification using computed RPCs has distortions and artifacts
Orthorectifying an image with RPCs computed (using this library) based on a manually marked set of GCPs and an elevation model gives an output which looks something like what I've attached below ( used a DTM of about 2.5m spatial resolution)
Although the output image aligns well with the basemap, the image is hugely distorted and has artifacts.
Could this be a result of poor/lack of GCP markings or something that could be fixed with particular process changes within the RPC computation and/or image transformation/warping module?

